# What should I do with my VPS?

Tags: vps

Well it turns out I had a VPS a few months ago, and I canceled it, turns out they canceled my billing, but never canceled my VPS, so I am basically using a free VPS. I have no idea what I should put on it, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Call them, and notify of them of their error.  You're technically commiting theft and/or fraud.

Comment: Definitely contact them. Legal or not, it's likely a violation of your contract with them (likely their violating the contract too by keeping your 'server' online when you've requested it be taken off.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put anything important... you might find it disappear one day.

Answer (score 2):

DNS, remote logging or using it as a VPN are some pretty good ideas.

Answer (score 2):

folding @ home. Make the most of accidental goodwill, never know, might cure cancer.